# Springboot findByDate Mysql

Tags: sql, spring-boot, date, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm encountering a problem to find the results of a database that was created during 2 dates.
Currently if I am looking for results between 2020-11-01 and 2020-11-02, the query only returns results from 2020-11-01 and not from 2020-11-02.

Same if I search between two identical dates, I get no results...

What I wish is that by searching between 01 and 02, it returns me the results that have been realized between these two dates so results in 2020-11-01 and 2020-11-02.

I would also like this request to work for two identical dates.

I hope it's possible ! :)
Thanks for help

My Repository

```
List<HistoriqueDeploiement> findByNamespaceIdAndLogCreatedAtBetween(Integer id_namespace, Date date_debut, Date date_fin);
```

My controller :

```
@GetMapping("/historiquedeploiement/namespace/{namespace}/date/{date_debut}/{date_fin}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<HistoriqueDeploiementReadingDTO>> GetHistoriqueDeploiementfindByNamespaceIdMapping(@PathVariable String namespace, @PathVariable("date_debut") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date_debut, @PathVariable("date_fin") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date_fin) throws InternalServerErrorException {
        Integer idnamespace = namespaceRepository.findByNamespace(namespace).getId();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mappingHistoriqueToDTO.findByNamespaceIdAndLogCreatedAtBetweenMapping(idnamespace, date_debut, date_fin), HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
```

Comment: Why not query for between(date1,date2+1)

Comment: Because i think it's a "bad fix", i'm sure we can do it better  
It's a date format not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we expect when we use `between` is to fetch records created from 2020-11-01 until the end of 2020-11-02. This unfortunately is not the case. What really happened is:

```
created_at between '2020-11-01 00:00:00+00000' and '2020-11-02 00:00:00+00000'
```

To retrieve records between 2020-11-01 and 2020-11-02, you have to add 1 day to your end date. By doing so, your query will be equivalent to:

```
created_at between '2020-11-01 00:00:00+00000' and '2020-11-03 00:00:00+00000'
```

---

I know this is related to Spring JPA but this is also a good read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: Ok i understand, i will use `Date date_finPlusOne = new DateTime(date_fin).plusDays(1).toDate();``
Thanks